# CKAN: per-hour horizontal axis in graph view

Tags: ckan

I'm trying to depict a dataset in CKAN, something simple: horizontal axis is based on a timestamp column in the DataStore, vertical axis is the value of certain measure.

My problem is I have several measures per hour, nevertheless CKAN graphs seem to consider days as the minimum time division. How to achive a per-hour horizontal axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is that you can't really - there are hardly any configuration options that you might like like axis maximum, axis interval etc.. I've worked a lot on extending the graphing for different purposes and it is possible to funnel properties through by extending the code (the underlying library is Flot which is extremely flexible albeit by now fairly outdated).

Purely for purposes of getting what you want, you might want to try the extension http://extensions.ckan.org/extension/basiccharts/ - could be that it will do a better job in this case.